# repeat css background image a set number of times

Tags: css, repeat

is there a way to set the number of times a background image repeats with css?

Answer (score 43):

An ugly hack could be inserting multiple times —statically— the same image (using [multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds)):

E.g. To repeat horizontally an image (80x80) three times:

```
background-image: url('bg_texture.png'), 
                  url('bg_texture.png'),
                  url('bg_texture.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat, 
                   no-repeat,
                   no-repeat;
background-position: 0 top, 
                     80px top,
                     160px top;
```

Beware: not working on IE under 9 version ([source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds)).

Comment: You should only need no-repeat written once, for the simplest version

Comment: This is a beautiful hack (not really a hack though, since it's supported by the syntax. Just feels like a hack)

Answer (score 8):

no.

you might set a absolute width for a box 
but there is no css option to repeat the image n times.

Comment: Short of setting a width or height to restrict the visual amount of repeating, or manually repeating the area in a single image, yes, this.

Answer (score 4):

Yes! You can set the background image size: background-size: 20%, 20%; This will make it repeat 5 times.

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is set the `background-size`. If you want to repeat background 2 times, set `background-size: 50%;`, 3 times, `background-size: 33.3%;`, 4 times, `background-size: 25%;`.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst not strictly repeating an image x-number of times, as @gcbenison stated, you can use the `background-repeat: space` property or, similarly, the `background-position: round` and combine either of these with `background-size` to ensure a set number of repetitions for a background image are shown, and then perhaps adjust the size of the wrapper to accomodate.

Both `space` and `repeat` will repeat a background image infinitely as long as the entire image can be shown, though for any remainder `space` will add a gap between the images whilst `round` will scale the images. Put simply, if the background image fits 3.342 times vertically then both `space` and `round` will show the image 3 times, with `space` adding a gap between each repeated image, and `round` scaling the images up (or down, if necessary) to fill the gap.

If you thus wanted to repeat an image 5 times, with each image being 20px wide and spaced 5px between, you could simply do this:

```
.star-rating {
    width: 120px;
    background-image: url('example.jpg');
    background-repeat: space;
    background-size: 20px auto;
    }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat

The other option (if you cannot set the width) is to use the solution from @franzlorenzon and simply declare the background x-number of times using the multiple background CSS property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds

In addition, you can save typing out multiple lines using SASS by creating a `@for` loop like so:

```
$image_count: 5;
$image_url: 'url(star.svg)';
$image_position: '0';

@for $i from 1 through ($image_count - 1) {
    $image_url: #{ $image_url+', '+$image_url };
    $image_position: #{ $image_position+', '+($i * (100% / $image_count)) };
}

.star-rating {
    background-image: $image_url;
    background-position: $image_position;
    background-size: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

This will then generate the background images, all evenly spaced out. Additionally feel free to change `($i * (100% / $image_count))` to `($i * VALUE)` for fixed spacing.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine a little jQuery with CSS to achieve what you want.
Say you want to display the image foo.png 3 times horizontally and 2 times vertically.

CSS:

```
body {
    background: url('foo.png');
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').css('background-size', $(window).width()/3 + 'px ' + $(window).height()/2 + 'px');
});
```

Additionally, you could paste the same code within $(window).resize() to get a dynamic response.

Comment: Alternatively you could simply set the background-size CSS value as 33.33% 50%. I feel jQuery will yield a  more precise value though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what originally motivated this question, but I found it searching for a way to make sure only an integral number of copies of a background image appears (i.e. do not crop the final member of a repeated set of background images.)  That can be achieved via the `background-repeat: space` property.