# Background repeat, choose how many repeats CSS

Tags: css

Can I choose, through CSS, how many times the background image is repeated?

Comment: im curious to know what it is that you are trying to achieve with repeating background specific amount of times?

Comment: possible duplicate of [repeat css background image a set number of times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949606/repeat-css-background-image-a-set-number-of-times)

Answer (score 5):

no, you can not specify how many times a background is repeated. the only options you have are: `no-repeat`, `repeat-y`, `repeat-x` and `repeat`

Answer (score 4):

You can set an absolute width for a box, but you can't choose the number of times the background image is repeated.

Comment: This answers the question AND provides hints to an alternate solution

Answer (score 1):

With regular CSS its only possible to select if and in which direction (horizontal or/and vertical) the background repeats.

Answer (score 0):

You can't limit the number of repeats. Either you display the image once, or repeat it to either the length or height of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. It will repeat (x, y or both) for the entire element width/height. You can set the element's size to a multiple of your background image width/height.