# Is there a way to set how long the repeat-x repeats for (in pixels or %)?

Tags: css, styles, repeat

I have an image that I am using as a divider that is basically a colon (:) repeated across the page, however instead of going all the way across I only want it to go about 80% or around 700px. Is there some CSS to set how far the image repeats?

Comment: Same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949606/repeat-css-background-image-a-set-number-of-times)

Comment: Just wrap your content in a div, set the div to 80% width and apply the background to that div..

Comment: I tried this without success...

HTML
     `<div class="h-wrapper-rtl h2 grid_12">
<span class="rtl-line"></span><h2 style="float:right;">Pre-Construction Phase</h2>
</div>`

CSS

`.h-wrapper-rtl {
 width: 700px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 background: url(/images/divider.png) 0 center repeat-x;
 float: left;
}`

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the image in a div that is 700px wide and set the background image repeat-x to 100%?

Comment: I tried this without success...

HTML
     `<div class="h-wrapper-rtl h2 grid_12">
<span class="rtl-line"></span><h2 style="float:right;">Pre-Construction Phase</h2>
</div>`

CSS

`.h-wrapper-rtl {
 width: 700px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 background: url(/images/divider.png) 0 center repeat-x;
 float: left;
}`

Comment: If you want your text to come right after the border I'd float them both to left. Also your border holder will need a height and I changed it to div. http://jsfiddle.net/mickadoo/XvMeP/