# background-size with background repeat counts with noticeable deviation

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-size, background-repeat

I've created square image and used it as repeated background-image for div.

 
https://jsfiddle.net/cethbqog/2/ 

I applied it with:

```
background-size: 5% auto;
```

And I supposed that will be 20 cells in a row but it didn't happen.
Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: I want to make a adaptive block with square 20 x 6. Width of container present in %.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be 20 cells in a row you should give the container a width of 400px and not 412px.

```
.container {
  width: 400px;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .4) url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABcAAAAXCAYAAADgKtSgAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAYdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHBhaW50Lm5ldCA0LjAuNWWFMmUAAAA3SURBVEhL7cwxEQAgDMVQXP+tNYedKmDBQEbY8u6yZnX3Xr84R86Rc+QcOUfOkXNUVSfJvC9zAWrdZxj51zBJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);   
  background-size: 5% auto;
}
```

**EDIT**

So what you are trying to do is to make background-image always have like 20 cells on x-axis while it's scalable and the height should always be = width. So this is hard to achieve i think with background-image. What I could think of is doing a png or svg with only one square and then insert it 20 times as background-image with repeat on y-axis. Normally you can't set a fixed number of background-repeats, but there seems to be a little hack to this i found here:
[repeat css background image a set number of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949606/repeat-css-background-image-a-set-number-of-times) (it will not work in IE9 and earlier)

```
background-image: url('square.png'), 
                  url('square.png'),
                  url('square.png');
background-repeat: repeat-y, 
                   repeat-y,
                   repeat-y;
background-size: 5% auto, 
                 5% auto, 
                 5% auto;
background-position: left top,
                     5% top,
                     10% top;
```

So i can't guarantee you this will work, but you can at least try it :)

Comment: Ok,  but it's a little bit strange way to apply size in percentage. Can I avoid such behaviour and make them really 5% width, like how it works for blocks.

Comment: Marcel Wasilewski is'nt 5% x 20% = 100% and i have check its hapen only in chrome in firfoxe its fine with 20 boxes so its mean this is browser problem

Comment: yeah you would have to insert the background 20 times, not just 3, i thought this is logical...

Answer (score 0):

[Modified a bit to achieve, please check it](https://jsfiddle.net/cethbqog/5/)

```css
.container {
  width: 420px;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .4) url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABcAAAAXCAYAAADgKtSgAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAYdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHBhaW50Lm5ldCA0LjAuNWWFMmUAAAA3SURBVEhL7cwxEQAgDMVQXP+tNYedKmDBQEbY8u6yZnX3Xr84R86Rc+QcOUfOkXNUVSfJvC9zAWrdZxj51zBJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);   
  background-size: 5.1% auto;
}
```